# Starting Asp.Net Website Automatically on windows startup

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I want to start my asp.net application when my windows 7 x64 starts.
I have manually start IIS to start my asp.net website.

Please suggest me to way to do this task.

Comment: By default it is set to start on startup. Run>`ingetmgr`> see right hand side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the path..

> Start>Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Services>World Wide Web Publishing Service>Right click on that service>Properties> Set **startup type** =Automatic >OK

Done!! you will get your localhost site in start up!!